# Why does script-type have "text/" prepended to it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why does script-type have "text/" prepended to it?

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" />
<link type="text/css"/>
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
```

Probably the standard javascript/vbscript/css  are defined as

```
<MIME-media-type>/<MIME-sub-type>
```

What about Handlebars - why does it follow the same format? (and same with few other libs)

And if I wish to add a custom type for my open-source-lib (e.g: nirman)... should it be written as:

```
<script type="nirman" /> 
/// OR
<script type="text/nirman" />
```

?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at RFC2046 -> http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt
You might find something useful there :)

Comment: And `type="text/javascript"` is no longer needed in html5, just plain `<script>` will do

Comment: Mime types always follow a set/subset pattern and most platforms adhere to this representational stance. As the previous comment suggests, mime type is optional for a really really long time and browsers hardly check that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does script-type have "text/" prepended to it?

It doesn't … `text/javascript` was [obsoleted in favour of `application/javascript`](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt).

> What about Handlebars - why does it follow the same format?

… but your question seems to be more about why MIME types come in two parts. That is defined [by the MIME specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt) to divide the MIME type into a general category (from a small selection on infrequently updated choices) and a specific type.

> And if I wish to add a custom type for my open-source-lib (e.g: nirman)... should it be written as

Neither.

Firstly, if you are writing a scripting language, then you should use `application`, not `text`:

> text -- textual information … subtypes are to be used for enriched text in forms where application software may enhance the appearance of the text, but such software must not be required in order to get the general idea of the content
>
> application -- some other kind of data, … information to be processed by an application.

Secondly, since you are making this up and don't have a public standard for it, the subtype should be prefixed with `X`

> A media type value beginning with the characters "X-" is a private
>      value, to be used by consenting systems by mutual agreement.  Any
>      format without a rigorous and public definition must be named with an
>      "X-" prefix,

So you should use: `application/x-nirman`

Comment: Thanks. Mine is not a new scripting languange - its javascript, but extracted and removed from html, and executed in a special context. Additionally, if it matters, application also considers that as a code-section under file-metadata. So in that case it should be "text/x-nirman-code" ...right?

Comment: `text/javascript` is still the media type name that actually works best in browsers, *if* you specify media type for JavaScript in `<script type=...>`. “Deprecation” is just words here, and misleading words.

Comment: Zeroed down to "application/x-nirman-code" for my requirement.. After reading more into the confusion and obsoletion on "text/javascript", it looks like "application/javascript" is considered to be better.

Answer (score 2):

Media type (MIME type) names generally consist of a major media type and a subtype, separated by a slash “/”. This is specified in [RFC 2406](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046).

The major type chosen for JavaScript is `text`, because JavaScript code *is* text. It can be directly read by human beings – who need to understand JavaScript of course, that’s why it is not *plain* text (`text/plain`). Later, various other media types have been proposed for JavaScript, for rather theoretical reasons, but `text/javascript` is what all browsers recognize.

[Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) seems to use `text/x-handlebars-template`.

If you want to use, within a `script` element, code that is not JavaScript code but will be processed by JavaScript code that interprets it as data of some kind (possibly as program code in some language), then the safest bet is to use `text/plain`. Not because of logic, but because of a statement in HTML5 CR about [scripting languages](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#scriptingLanguages). It lists a few media type names that “must not be interpreted as scripting language”, and among the alternatives, `text/plain` is probably the least illogical.

The point here is to prevent browsers from executing the script element content as JavaScript (or as VBScript), so you *need* to specify a `type` attribute, with a value that will make the browser refrain from doing what browsers normally do with `script` elements. The browser will then just store the content in the DOM, for your JavaScript code to deal with.

Yes, this is illogical if your code is, in some sense, program code, and you are doing your best to tell browsers that it isn’t. But it’s not program code natively interpreted by the browser.

Using `text/x-nirman` or `application/x-nirman` would most probably work too. Or anything that does not look suspiciously like referring to JavaScript or VBScript.

Comment: Isn't `text/javascript` obsolete, like Quentin mentions in his answer?

Comment: `text/javascript` is said to be obsolete in an *informational* RFC (i.e., a document that is not presented as authoritative, or even as being “on standards track”). HTML5, which is work in progress, but much more influential than that RFC, uses `text/javascript` freely.